# $http.jsonp not wrapping angular.callbacks

Tags: angularjs, http, jsonp

My function

```
$scope.doCall = function(){
            console.log('test');
            $http.jsonp('http://api.v2.quran.com/info/surah?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
            success(function(data) {
              // this callback will be called asynchronously
              // when the response is available
              console.log(data[0]);
            })
            var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });


        }
```

When I look at my network, the second call wraps `angular.callbacks._1(OBJECT)` while the first just returns `[...ARRAY OF OBJECTS...]`

The second will output in my console, the first is not doing anything! How can i make it work!

Answer (score 1):

Thats API problem, http://api.v2.quran.com didn't wrap JSON to JSON_CALLBACK, in second case JSON starts with JSON_CALLBACK({... but in first case you get pure JSON, not JSONP. Try to fix it on server.